# Did Jesus refuse to answer Herod (Luke 23:11) because of what Jesus taught in Matthew 10:13?

Tags: jesus

Luke 23:11

> Herod and his soldiers treated him contemptuously and mocked him, and
> after clothing him in resplendent garb, he sent him back to Pilate.

After Jesus preached the great sermon to the thousands, he prepared his disciples to compass the land in all directions. He mentions anyone who does not listen and says to pay no attention to them. (Matthew 10:13)

So when Herod mocked Jesus, could this be reason why Jesus never spoke to Herod? Did he pay no attention because when Jesus spoke with Pilate, Nicodemus and others felt he was the son of man but unwilling to commit themselves publicly to it?

Comment: Welcome to BH. There is a question on this site which asks "Why did Jesus not respond to Herod?" [Luke 23:9]. Have you read it? Does it answer your question?

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site and as to how it differs from other sites, being an _hermeneutic_ site which analyses questions containing specific text from the scripture. Without the provision of text we cannot make an _hermeneutic_ analysis.

Comment: Suggestion: 1. edit your headline question to something like "Why did Jesus refuse to answer Herod?"  2. Include the  bible verse related to your question.

Comment: I added biblical verses and also edited it a bit for clarity.  Because the question addresses a specific idea not mentioned in the possible duplicate I leave it to the moderators to decide if it needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The question: "Herod mocked Jesus; could this be reason as why Jesus never spoke to Herod?" The answer must be no, because Jesus' refusal to answer came prior to Herod's mocking.

Luke 23

> 8 Herod was very glad to see Jesus; he had been wanting to see him for
> a long time, for he had heard about him and had been hoping to see him
> perform some sign.  He questioned him at length, but he gave him no
> answer.

It is only after this that Antipas mocked Jesus.

So we really do not know why Jesus refused to answer him. One reason may be a question of jurisdiction. The charges against Jesus were brought by the high priesthood in Jerusalem and referred to Pilate, who was the governor of Judea. Antipas was the ruler of the Galilee and neighboring provinces. He did not have legal authority in this case, let alone divine authority. It is also possible that Jesus trusted Antipas less than Pilate, because Antipas had already put John the Baptist to death. Also, it may be that Jesus wanted his execution to take place in Jerusalem and was concerned that if Antipas passed judgment, he might be brought back to the Galilee, which was not in accord with God's plan.  Finally, the OP's suggestion is also worth consideration: that in Pilate's court there were potential allies such as Nicodemus, Pilate's wife, Joseph of Arimathea, etc.

**Conclusion**: it is not possible to know for certain from the text why Jesus refused to answer Herod Antipas. It does not seem to be the case that Herod was less open to Jesus than Pilate was, at least at first. More likely reasons for Jesus' silence include that Pilate had legal jurisdiction over the case while Herod did not, or that Jesus had potential allies in Pilate's court.